# Want to change this format $1,000,000 to 1000000 this

Tags: php

Well i have calculator. In which i want to accept value in this `$1,000,000` format

so below are my codes want to know how to replace them using php

Live: http://ffsng.deewayz.in/index.php?v=1000000&sv=1951153458

I just want to know code to replace them with php this `$1,000,000` to this `1000000` and also if float can accept this value or have to change float to some other.

My HTML

```
Enter Present Value of Pet: <input type="text" name="v" value="1000000"/><br>
Enter value of pet you want: <input type="text" name="sv" value="1951153458"/><br>
```

My PHP

```
$v         = isset($_GET['v']) ? (float) $_GET['v'] : 1000000;
$sv        = isset($_GET['sv']) ? (float) $_GET['sv'] : 1951153458;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function reverse_number_format($num)
{
    $num = (float)str_replace(array(',', '$'), '', $num);
}
```

Comment: just confused what change i need to make int his? **$v = isset($_GET['v']) ? (float) $_GET['v'] : 1000000;**

Comment: `isset($_GET['v']) ? (float) reverse_number_format($_GET['v']) : 1000000;

Comment: lol thanks so much i was trying to get value first and then changing it and you did it in one line :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use preg_replace to remove the $ and the ,

```
$v  = preg_replace('/[\$,]/', '', $v);
$sv = preg_replace('/[\$,]/', '', $sv);
```

Comment: preg_replace sounds overkill-ish for this.

Comment: yup, its like cutting a lemon with a sword.